# MongoDB C# driver and filtered positional operator $[<identifier>] with typed API

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that has documents that look like the following:

```
{
    "Name" : "Name1",
    "AA" : [ 
        {
            "B" : {
                "Name" : "Name2"
            },
            "CC" : [ 
                {
                    "Field" : "Value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am working from C# with the 2.7 MongoDB driver.

I want to push an element to the CC array of those elements of AA that match a certain condition. I was able to do that with following code:

```
[TestFixture]
class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var b = new B { Name = "Name2" };
        var c = new C { Field = "Value2" };

        var field = new StringFieldDefinition<Document>("AA.$[element].CC");
        var updateDefinition = Builders<Document>
            .Update
            .Push(field, c);

        var arrayFilterBson = new BsonDocument("element.B",
            new BsonDocument("$eq", b.ToBsonDocument()));
        var arrayFilter = new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<AgentRecord>(arrayFilterBson);

        var documentFilter = Builders<Document>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Name, "Name1");

        var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions 
        { 
            IsUpsert = false,
            ArrayFilters = new ArrayFilterDefinition[] {  arrayFilter }
        };

        var settings = new MongoClientSettings
        {
            Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27000)
        };

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("so-question");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Document>("collection");
        collection.UpdateOne(documentFilter, updateDefinition, updateOptions);
    }
}

// Mapping classes
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A[] AA { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C[] CC { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

**Is there a way to achieve the same through the typed API to avoid having to hardcode the name of the fields in definitions such as `AA.$[element].CC` or `element.B`?**

I am of course worried about having to change these hard-coded expressions when the name of the properties of the classes change or for example if I make use of the `[BsonElement("name")]` attribute to control the name of the mapped property.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am having same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I used my hard-coded solution and at some point I stopped working with MongoDB. I'm still interested to know the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really late, but in case anyone else comes across this looking for an answer like I did, try Mongo's [AllMatchingElements](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_MongoEnumerable_AllMatchingElements__1.htm) method:

> Represents all matching elements in an array when using an array filter (corresponds to the server's "$[identifier]" update operator).

So `updateDefinition` would instead be

```
var updateDefinition = Builders<Document>.Update.Push(
    doc => doc.AA.AllMatchingElements("element").CC,
    c);
```